# Producing Attic Greek numerals

Tags: fonts

I know the `teubner` package can produce Attic Greek numerals with the `\AtticNumeral` command, but their appearance is quite different from what numerals are used in history of math textbooks. For instance, in Howard Eves' textbook on the history of mathematics, he gives the following representation of the number 2857:

[image]

Is there a way to produce these symbols for the different numerals (particularly the symbols that incorporate the use of 5 -- the third and seventh symbols above, from left to right, respectively)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use the font Quivira for this. Generally I would search the symbol fifty in [unicode](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/10144/index.htm) and see, which [fonts](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/10144/fontsupport.htm) are supported there.

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}    
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \setmainfont{quivira.otf}
    \begin{tabular}{S[table-format=5.2,group-four-digits=true]l}
        \toprule
        {Arabic} & Attic Greek\\
        \midrule
        0.25 & \symbol{"10140}\\
        0.5 & \symbol{"10141}\\
        1 & \symbol{"0399}\\ % usual Iota
        5 & \symbol{"10143}\symbol{"03A0}\\ % second: usual Pi
        10 & \symbol{"0394}\\ % usual Delta
        50 & \symbol{"10144}\\
        100 & \symbol{"0397}\\ % usual Eta
        500 & \symbol{"10145}\\
        1000 & \symbol{"03A7}\\ % usual Chi
        5000 & \symbol{"10146}\\
        10000 & \symbol{"039C}\\ % usual Mu
        50000 & \symbol{"10147}\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Your example could be set (using FreeSerif) like this:

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Biolinum O}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\newfontfamily\atticFont{freeserif.otf} 
\newcommand*{\atOne}{{\atticFont\symbol{"0399}}}
\newcommand*{\atFive}{{\atticFont\symbol{"10143}}}
\newcommand*{\atFifty}{{\atticFont\symbol{"10144}}}
\newcommand*{\atHundret}{{\atticFont\symbol{"0397}}}
\newcommand*{\atFiveHundret}{{\atticFont\symbol{"10145}}}
\newcommand*{\atThousand}{{\atticFont\symbol{"03A7}}}

\begin{document}
    \blindtext%
    \begin{center}
        2857 = \atThousand\atThousand\atFiveHundret\atHundret\atHundret\atHundret\atFifty\atFive\atOne\atOne
    \end{center}
    \blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

In order to get automatic calculation like `\atticNum{2857}` you will have to do another question or wait for real programmers to help out. You could search this site for the calculation of Roman numerals and use the routines you find there. Or you ask Claudio Beccari to add an option for unicode mapping to his package `teubner`. This would omit to program it again.

Comment: Very nice! One very minor quibble: The repeated direct use of `\fontspec` (as part of the `\AtticFont` macro) is called "inefficient" in section 5 of the `fontspec` user guide. Instead, issue the command `\newfontfamily\atticFont{freeserif.otf}`, followed by `\newcommand*{\atOne}{{\atticFont\symbol{"0399}}}`, etc. (Note the extra pair of curly braces, which localizes the scope of the `\atticFont` switch.

Comment: @Mico Thank you for the feedback. Actually I was surprised I did not need these braces... But the `\newfontfamily` looks much better. Will add that in a second.

Answer (score 5):

Complementing @LaRiFaRi 's answer, both `polyglossia` and `xgreek` contain an `atticnum` command which you can use to produce the numbers (up to a certain limit) in Attic format:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{greek}

\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{FreeSerif}

\begin{document}
\begin{greek}\atticnum{2857}\end{greek}
\end{document}
```

In `polyglossia` you need to be in a greek language environment for the command to be available.

Answer (score 1):

```
%LuaLaTex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}    

\begin{document}
    \setmainfont{FreeSerif}
    {\huge\bf
   \hspace{-2.6cm} \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline
       $1$ & $5$ & $10$ & $50$ & $100$ & $500$ & $1\,000$ & $5\,000$ & $10\,000$  \\ \hline
   \symbol{"0399} & \symbol{"10143} \symbol{"03A0} & \symbol{"0394} & \symbol{"10144} & \symbol{"0397} & \symbol{"10145} & \symbol{"03A7} & \symbol{"10146} & \symbol{"039C} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}}
\end{document}
```

Note: Download FreeSerif to the same directory and use LuaLaTeX. You obtain a simple table of attic numeration.